# What are some of the usages of Picard's little theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I know that it is an important theorem in itself, but what really makes it such as great result?

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187020/applications-of-the-small-and-great-theorems-of-picard

Answer (score 0):

This result has nice applications. For example, you can use it to prove that every non constant polynomial with complex coefficients has a root in the complex plane (the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra).

Comment: A bit of a sledgehammer...

Comment: Another application : the sum of the exponentials of two entire functions has either no zeroes, or infinitely many.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What is a sledgehammer? Both PLT and the FTA are huge, deep results. That FTA can be proved with this advanced result doesn't meant that it is overkilling...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, using PLT to prove FTA is overkill. That's not something that can be proved mathematically, but deep or not, FTA is _much_ easier than PLT.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't think so. Overkill is using a powerful machinery to prove something way more basic. Not the case at all...but I guess that's a matter of personal taste.